# How can I import stations listed by RepeaterBook as FM and other things into my HTs with CHIRP?

Tags: uv-5r

I've programmed both my UV-5RA and FT-4XR via CHIRP and it has generally worked fine.  However, one thing I'm not understanding is why it is refusing to program some stations from RepeaterBook input where plain, old FM appears to be listed as one of the supported modes.

For example, this one: https://www.repeaterbook.com/repeaters/details.php?state_id=25&ID=3277

That does say it is P25-enabled but it also says it is FM analog-capable.  And on the proximity search page it says "FM EchoLink P-25" for this station.  But CHIRP refuses to import it into the radio images.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that RepeaterBook apparently is reporting `P25` as the only supported mode when running (and importing) the RB proximity query from inside of CHIRP.

The reason I believe this is that when I export the RepeaterBook search to a CHIRP-compatible CSV the value of the mode column for that station is `P25`.

If I then edit the CSV and change `P25` to `FM` and then do Import CSV instead of Import RB Proximity Query I get can that repeater uploaded into my radios.